# Using Windows 10 v 1507 Safe or not?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, security, firewall

- In my company, the pc's are running Windows 10 Enterprise but most of them are running v 1507 the very first from 2015.
- Anytime the tech support has to set up a new PC for someone, they install the same image(v 1507) and nobody here updates their PC's(In fact they can't I think).
- So, is this a security issue(Since support has ended for v 1507 to v 1703) or are there other measures followed in a company and there is not much need to worry about this ...I don't know anything about this from a security point of view. In fact some PC's here are still on Windows 7.
- Is this something worth discussing about with my boss or will I just look stupid ?

Comment: "Safe" is very subjective.

Comment: Do you know if they're using the standard or LTSB branch?

Comment: @grawity I really don't think it is LTSB but is there any way I can check on my PC ?

Comment: @grawity Sorry I forgot that I have already checked that and yes it is not LTSB, I checked from the registry value and power shell also.

Comment: @grawity but I had updated my PC using an admin account.I am on v 1809. Would updating affect the LTSB, Assuming there was any ?

Comment: Such an old version is truly unsafe because more modern security updates cannot happen. Once you update past about V1803, Windows will update itself no matter what and that is what you should do. V1903 is current and V1909 is due out in about 30 days. Windows 7 is at end of support in 2 months and you have to pay to get Windows 7 security updates after this coming January 1. You should update your systems for sure.

Comment: Your IT department is horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version is probably the Windows 10 LTSB version 1507.
LTSB versions cannot be updated via Windows Update, except for security patches.

The Microsoft announcement applies here of
[Windows 10 v1507 End of Servicing for CB and CBB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018798/windows-10-v1507-end-of-servicing-for-cb-and-cbb):

> End of servicing for Current Branch (CB) and Current Branch for Business (CBB) will occur on May 9, 2017.
>
> This means that v1507 will no longer receive security updates after the May update.
>
> Customers are encouraged to update to the latest CB and CBB to remain supported.

This means that the company has missed out of all security updates since May 2017.
We are talking here about protection from almost two and a half years of newly
discovered viruses and attacks.

This is certainly something worth discussing about with your boss.
You are certainly not being stupid about it by any means.

Comment: The only question that remains is how on Earth they have _still_ been working since May 2,017 to the Present Date.

Comment: @harrymc  But I was able to update my pc via Windows update after switching to an admin account...I remember that it would show me windows updating and then after an hour or so it would roll back all the changes but then after several tries when one time I restarted the PC, it did finally update. Would updating cancel its LTSB status ? My pc does not show it as LTSB so I guess I will check on some other pc's as well to verify about LTSB.

Comment: I guessed LTSB as an explanation for the company being stuck in v1507. If you did manually Windows Update then your settings determine what updates will be offered.